# Cant log in from manually entered credentials for admin ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I was following this tutorial (https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/user-management-in-aspnet-core-mvc/). I followed the tutorial till adding a default user (for admin purposes). I can view the added user in the database but cannot log in. On the other hand, if I register a user on the website (using the registration form), I can log in to that account. Can someone please help me?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CoWh74vwjstVIfJztwRoEuQmWGsceiR7/view?usp=sharing This is the link to my project file. Kindly take a look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you can't log in the `admin@gmail.com` account? But i try your code and use this account, It can log in successfully.

Comment: @XinranShen Can I somehow contact you? I mean google meet or WhatsApp, I need some help in learning C#. It will be great if u can help me a little.